# Storage Problems on Android 4.4 Tablet

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, storage, tablet

I have a cheap tablet with Android 4.4.2.

- Manufactorer: JTY
- Model: KT07B

I need some help understanding the Storage and how to organize it. Here is a screenshot of the "storage"-item in the settings:

[image: Screenshot of storage]

The storage is divided into `Phone Storage` and `Internal Storage`
There is an SD-Card slot at the tablet, but there is no card inserted, so there is no "SDCard Storage".

My first question is: **What is the difference between those 2 storage-types?**

As you can see "Internal Storage" is pretty full. I tried to move every app into the "Phone Storage". But for almost every app, the option "Move to Phone storage" is disabled. So my second question is: **Why is this option disabled?**

When I try to install a new (big) app from the playstore, I get the error message, that there is not enough space. So my third question is: **How can I install new apps to "Phone storage" where there is a lot of space left, instead of the almost full "internal storage".**

Under "Default Write Disk" there already is "phone storage", but nevertheless every app that I try to install warns about the few remaining storage.

On the 2nd Screenshot you can see an example: I cannot move this (freshly installed) app to the phone storage...

[image]

EDIT:

This other link doesn't help at all. E.g. it does not explain, why I can't save most of my apps on the "phone-storage", but some few apps can be stored there...

Comment: Did you visit the wikis attached to the tags you attached to your question? At least storage and internal-storage have a number of attached questions devoted to their explanation. See the 'Info' hyperlink of each attained by hovering over the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal storage, phone storage and SD card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33464/internal-storage-phone-storage-and-sd-card)